# Laravel 5.6 passing eloquent model as parameter to a function

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5.6

I have a selection control on a blade form that is to be refreshed via ajax through this function:

```
function getOpciones(tbName) {
    $.get('/ajax/read-data/' + tbName, function(data){
    return (data);
});
}
```

The function takes a string variable 'tbName' whith the name of the table the control is related to, and passes it on as a parameter to the route:

```
Route::get('/ajax/read-data/{modelo}', 'AjaxController@readData');
```

Then the controller should get the parameter {modelo}, and retrieve the records in that table:

```
use App\RegFiscal;

public function readData($modelo) {
    $arreglo = $modelo::all();
    return response($arreglo);
}
```

But even though I am referencing the model with 'use App\RegFiscal', all I get is this error in laravel log:

> 2018-03-23 18:52:08] local.ERROR: exception
>   'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message
>   'Class 'RegFiscal' not found' in
>   C:\wamp64\www\laravel\cte\app\Http\Controllers\AjaxController.php:32

I´m new to Laravel, so needless to say I am lost and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you `use App\RegFiscal` doesn't mean `$modelo` is associated with it.

What you can do, though, is use `app("App\\$modelo")` to load in your model based on the parameter you get from the router. You would no longer need to `use App\RegFiscal` either.

```
$arreglo = app("App\\$modelo");
return response($arreglo::all());
```

This is assuming your model is stored in the default `app` directory within your Laravel project. If not you can change `"App\"` to where ever it is stored. If for example your model is in `app\models\modelname.php` it would be `"App\Models\\$modelo"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as the following:

```
public function readData($modelo) {
$modelName = '\App' . '\\' . $modelo;
$class = new $modelName();
arreglo = $class::all();
return response($arreglo);
```

}

Comment: Thanks a lot ali. I tried it and it works perfectly. I´m voting Wild Beard's answer simply because it came in first and it´s shorter to type. Your solution however, provides more clarity when the query parameters on $class are longer than just $class::all();

Answer (score 0):

To those like me who wanted to inject it on a constructor, here's how to do it:

```
~$ php artisan make:provider MyProvider
```

Then override the register function like so:

```
class MyProvider implements ServiceProvider {

    /** @override */
    public function register() {
        $this->app->bind(ShapeInterface::class, function ($app) {
            return new Square($app->make(MyModel::class));
        });
    }
}
```

The `ShapeInterface` is a simple interface and `Square` is a simple class that implements the shape interface with a constructor parameter of the eloquent model.

```
class Square implements ShapeInterface {
    private MyModel $model;

    function __construct(MyModel $model) {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    ...
}
```